# Is it possible to create multiple rows in a single pass with an attribute with different values using the ORM?

Tags: laravel, orm

I'm sorry for the question's title, if you can help me to make it better I'd more than thankful.

Now the question: I have an app where my users do some predictions on games, like a sport poll. When I score they predictions I do several things because of the rules we have. The first thing I do is to assign a very unlikely prediction to the users that didn't make a prediction. I do this in order to give them some chance to win if they forgot to place their predictions.

So, first thing I do is to get all the users that did predict.

```
  $pronos = Pronostico::where('juego_id', $juego->id)
    ->pluck('user_id');
```

Then I use this info to get all the users that didn't predict...

```
  $users = User::whereNotIn('id', $pronos)->get();
```

And finally I create a prediction (Pronostico in spanish) for all these users:

```
  foreach ($users as $user) {
    Pronostico::create([
        'user_id' => $user->id,
        'prediction' => -4,
        // other attributes
    ]);
  }
```

Is there a way to take out that `foreach`? Like inserting several rows by passing the users in an array or something like that? something to make this cleaner?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use relationships, so directly get the same as the first 2 queries and do something with them. Try it out and see if it works for you as expected.

```php
User::doesntHave('pronosticos', function (Builder $query) use ($juego) {
    return $query->where('juego_id', $juego->id);
})
    ->pronosticos()
    ->create([
        'prediction' => -4,
    ]);
```

So, from all `Users` you only want those that do not have `pronosticos` (this part would be `->doesntHave('pronosticos')` and must match the relationship name between `User` and `Pronostico` models), then you go to the relationship (because you want to create pronosticos for them), and create with `prediction = -4`.

This should work as expected for you. More about [`doesntHave`](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-absence) on the docs.